# Fujitsu Arrows X F-02E Rooting

Tags: android, root

So today I tried to root my Docomo Fujitsu Arrows X F-02E , I installed ADB , I enabled USB debugging but when I try to run the root script I get this:

```
-- NTT Docomo Arrows X F-02E Rooting Script --

           !! Warning !!

/System is not mounted as R/W
F-02E_system-mounter script needs to be ran for R/W.
That script needs to be ran everytime the phone restarts

Press any key to continue . . .
Pushing the required files to /data/local/tmp

1197 KB/s (1283460 bytes in 1.047s)
980 KB/s (146652 bytes in 0.146s)
1089 KB/s (366952 bytes in 0.329s)
1159 KB/s (1578585 bytes in 1.329s)
chmod 0777 pwn and unlock_security_module

[+] This may take a few minutes.
[-] Failure.

Running unlock_security_module

Mapping kernel memory...
Detected kernel physical address at 0x80008000 form iomem
Attempt fb_mem_exploit...
OK.

Finding kallsyms address in memory...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Mounting /system as R/W to run the scripts

mount: Operation not permitted

Running root script

/system/xbin/su: cannot open for write: Read-only file system
Unable to chown /system/xbin/su: No such file or directory
Unable to chmod /system/xbin/su: No such file or directory

Mounting /system as R/O

mount: Operation not permitted

Installating Superuser.apk. DO NOT REPLACE IT OR UPDATE IT. RESULTS IN LOSS OF R
OOT

1176 KB/s (1578585 bytes in 1.310s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk
Success

Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the root script that I use:

```
@echo off
echo -- NTT Docomo Arrows X F-02E Rooting Script --
echo;
echo            !! Warning !!
echo;
echo /System is not mounted as R/W
echo F-02E_system-mounter script needs to be ran for R/W.
echo That script needs to be ran everytime the phone restarts
echo;

pause

echo Pushing the required files to /data/local/tmp
echo;
adb push .\pwn /data/local/tmp/pwn
adb push .\unlock_security_module /data/local/tmp/unlock_security_module
adb push .\su /data/local/tmp/su
adb push .\Superuser.apk /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk

echo chmod 0777 pwn and unlock_security_module
echo;
adb shell chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/pwn
adb shell chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/unlock_security_module
adb shell /data/local/tmp/pwn

echo;
echo Running unlock_security_module
echo;
adb shell /data/local/tmp/unlock_security_module

echo;
echo Mounting /system as R/W to run the scripts
echo;
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system

echo;
echo Running root script
echo;
adb shell dd if=/data/local/tmp/su of=/system/xbin/su
adb shell chown root.root /system/xbin/su
adb shell chmod 6755 /system/xbin/su

echo;
echo Mounting /system as R/O
echo;
adb shell mount -o ro,remount /system

echo;
echo Installating Superuser.apk. DO NOT REPLACE IT OR UPDATE IT. RESULTS IN LOSS OF ROOT
echo;
adb install .\Superuser.apk

echo;
echo Translated to English by anaschilling
echo;
pause
```

Is there any way to root this phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this is posted here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402784

This may not work for the latest version of the phone's OS (V19R50D)

Comment: Unfourtunately the version is V19R50D. Is there any way to root it?

Comment: If the method linked there does not work, I cannot find another one to offer you.  XDA would be a better place to ask this, IMO.